# Using a project from source control across repositories and solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

In one of our projects, we have a class library we use for more than one project/client and each of these solutions exist in different repositories.  Currently, this class library exists in it's own repository.  When we are referencing it in the client app, we compile it from one location, then copy the .dll to the other project's /libs/ folder so it can be used in that solution.

This is **dumb** and can be much better.  But I can't figure out a good way to commit changes that are made in the solution to both repositories.

What is the best way to include a class library from a separate repository into another solution in a different repository?

*Toolset: VS 2008, Subversion 1.6*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)?

Basically you designate one directory in your working copy as a "symbolic link" to another repository. When you update your main working copy you also get updates from external repository.

Another option would be to use some kind of central repository where you store the compiled .dlls. Something similar to Java world's [maven repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). I don't know if such beasts exists for Visual Studio.